# Eclipse plugin cannot find class from class folder

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-pde

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin, and want to use some pre-compiled classes which I've put to `lib/` folder in my project (so the directory structure looks like `{proj_root}/lib/com/example/Required.class`). Then I've added `lib/` folder as class folder to project's build path. At build time all is working fine, I can import and use that classes in my code. And now the problem is, when I'm running my plugin in separate Eclipse instance I get `ClassNotFoundException` by my plugin refering to class from precompiled classes folder.

I tried specifying my class folder in "Order and export" tab in Build path settings. Also I tried setting checkbox in plugin's build.properties GUI editor in front of `lib/` folder to be included in binary build. In that case if I export my plugin to JAR I can see `lib/` folder inside it, with my classfiles, but at runtime my plugin still cannot find any of classes from `lib/`.

Can you please give me an advice on how I should tell Eclipse where to find that classes at runtime?

PS.:

1. I did research on stackoverflow on this problem, but all suggestions are the same: just add class folder in project's Build path.
2. At this point in plugin's build.properties Text editor, eclipse shows warning `The class folder 'lib/' is not associated to any output library entry.` and suggests to make this modification of code:
   `output.. = bin/,lib/`. I have tried that solution but it is seems to change nothing with the problem.

Comment: take a look at the jar file if it contains the class file you need.

Comment: It does contain the class file (under lib/ folder, not as usual "my" classes, which are stored in root of plugin JAR), as I said, but latter cannot be found at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds very much like you have added the `lib` folder to the "Java Build Path" properties page of the plug-in project.

But... for plug-in projects, this does not work as these are OSGi bundles - you must include the `lib` folder in the PDE Editor on the "Runtime" page:

[image: Classpath description for OSGi]

Comment: Oh sorry for my previous comment, I haven't carefully red your advice and tried to add library in build.properties editor, not PDE (plugin.xml) editor. Thanks for your help, it worked.